# What was the role of state sacrifices and music in Ming China?

Tags: ancient-history, china, ancient-china

I don't understand what is the role of music in their lives and what is the relevance between sacrifices and music?

> As a historical ethnomusicologist, I wish I could do fieldwork in the Ming court, observing the court citizens and asking them why state sacrifices and music played such a central role in their public and private lives. The emperors and scholar-officials cannot be reached now, but they have left a wealth of evidence that they found their state sacrifices and music expressive.
>
> <sup>"[State Sacrifices and Music in Ming China](http://www.sunypress.edu/p-2735-state-sacrifices-and-music-in-m.aspx)" - Joseph S.C. Lam</sup>

"Methodologies for historical ethnomusicology in the twenty-first century" by David G.Hebert and Jonathan McCollum in

Comment: If you are quoting a passage, you need to provide a link or credit to the author or source.

Comment: The source is _Methodologies for historical ethnomusicology in the twenty-first century_ by David G.Hebert and Jonathan McCollum and this sentence is a quotation from Joseph Lam.

Comment: Actually the original source is: http://www.sunypress.edu/p-2735-state-sacrifices-and-music-in-m.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ceremony, even today, often integrates music into the process.  Think of the

- customary playing of '[Pomp and Circumstance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pomp_and_Circumstance_Marches)' during a graduation
  ceremony
- the National Anthem to begin a sporting event
- '[Hail to the Chief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hail_to_the_Chief)' announcing the entry of the President of the
  United States
- various national anthems to salute the medal winners at the Olympic
  games
- the [Wedding March](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedding_March_(Mendelssohn)) during a marriage
- or 'Amazing Grace' played on bagpipes during some funeral processions

.  This music is all integrated into our understanding of these events, and has become part of many of our current(american) ceremonies.

The Ming Dynasty was no different.  Several rituals were performed on a regular basis, and they had accompanying ritual music and dance performances. From [AsianArt.org](http://education.asianart.org/explore-resources/background-information/beliefs-and-religions-ming-dynasty-1368%E2%80%931644):

> Many of the rituals were seasonal, and by the Ming dynasty there was
>   at least one every month; these rituals took on prescribed forms with
>   carefully determined and properly performed dance, movement, and
>   sacrifices.

Two of the larger rituals, were the Sacrifice to Heaven, and the Sacrifices to Imperial Ancestors.  These were ritual type events, with very specific forms and procedures to be followed.

from wiki on the [Temple of Heaven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temple_of_Heaven):

> In ancient China, the Emperor of China was regarded as the Son of
>   Heaven, who administered earthly matters on behalf of, and
>   representing, heavenly authority. To be seen to be showing respect to
>   the source of his authority, in the form of sacrifices to heaven, was
>   extremely important. The temple was built for these ceremonies, mostly
>   comprising prayers for good harvests.
>
> Twice a year the Emperor and all his retinue would move from the
>   Forbidden City through Beijing to encamp within the complex, wearing
>   special robes and abstaining from eating meat. No ordinary Chinese was
>   allowed to view this procession or the following ceremony. In the
>   temple complex the Emperor would personally pray to Heaven for good
>   harvests. The highpoint of the ceremony at the winter solstice was
>   performed by the Emperor on the Earthly Mount. The ceremony had to be
>   perfectly completed; it was widely held that the smallest of mistakes
>   would constitute a bad omen for the whole nation in the coming year.

Ritual music forms in China are discussed in more detail, including intruements used and a sample audio file, under the heading [Yayue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yayue).

> Yayue (Chinese: 雅樂; literally: "elegant music") was originally a form
>   of classical music and dance performed at the royal court in ancient
>   China. The basic conventions of yayue were established in the Western
>   Zhou. Together with law and rites, it formed the formal representation
>   of aristocratic political power.

Answer (score 0):

The music of the Ming Dynasty was a "throwback" to ancient [Kun Qu](http://www.xip.fi/atd/china/the-ming-dynasty-1368-1644.html) music that went back roughly two millennia, to before the Birth of Christ. It was a deeper, sadder kind of music that the lively music favored by the Yuan (Mongol) dynasty. It harkened to a time when people lived barely on the edge of subsistence (most of China had advanced beyond that by the mid first Millennium, or what the Europeans call the Dark Ages), except that the Ming Dynasty was one of the more tragic dynasties in relatively modern Chinese histories. The idea of needing sacrifices to appease the gods was an element of Ming music, and notably absent from culture of other modern Chinese dynasties, while being a "staple" of the ancient ones, as well as many other non-Chinese cultures from before the birth of Christ.